# Apple Mail: All the mailboxes seems to be empty?

Tags: mail.app, email, time-machine, backup

I have installed a new HDD on my Macbook Pro. I can't reinstall OS from the Time Machine Backup, it reports an error, and asks me to run the install again. It is the same every time I try.
I have now used Migration Assistant to install Maverick from Time Machine, and it went well, except all of my mailboxes in Apple Mail seems to be empty.

My 3 email accounts are pop3 type.

I've tried to delete /library/mail/V2 and all it's content, and copied V2 from the Time Machine Backup to the Mac's Mail folder, but all mailboxes still seems to be empty? I know they are not, V2 is over 2 GB. What can I do?